# Parse JSON to list of POJO objects using POJO object class

Tags: java, json, groovy, gson

I am forced to use an interface method with the signature which I can not change:

```
List parse(String path, Class clazz)
```

It is supposed to return a list of objects with the type, passed in the `clazz` parameter, e.g.:

```
List<TagsRun> runs = reader.parse(path, TagsRun.class)
```

I need to implement a JSON parser and the question is how to set the type of `clazz` parameter to the result list?

I use Gson and it might be something like:

```
List parse(String path, Class clazz) {
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<TagsRun>>(){}.getType();
    List<TagsRun> myList = new Gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
    return myList 
}
```

But how to replace the particular **List< TagsRun >** with **List< type of clazz >** here?

The only working solution I did requires changing of the method signature:

```
<T> List<T> parse(String path, Class<T[]> clazz ) {
        T[] arr = new Gson().fromJson(new File(path).text(), clazz);
        return Arrays.asList(arr);
}
```

In other words, how to return the list of objects having the same type as `clazz` argument using the signature:

```
 List parse(String path, Class clazz)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, finally:

```
@Override
List parse(String path, Class clazz) {
    List result = []
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser()
            .parse(new File(path).getText(CHARSET))
            .getAsJsonArray()

    Gson gson = new Gson()
    jsonArray.each {
        result.add(gson.fromJson(it, clazz))
    }
    return result
}
```

The trick is to first get an array, and then use `gson.fromJson(it, clazz)` for each of array items. This will convert each json element in the array to POJO and then add it to result list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can not change the method's signature, there is no point in returning a List with type parameter.

```
public List foo() {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    return strings;
}

public void methodUsingFoo() {
    // possible but you should check if the assumption is correct:
    List<String> uncheckedAssignment = foo(); // so don't do this

    // this is what foo *will* return:
    List actualResult = foo();
}
```

Instead you could do something like this:

```
public void methodUsingParse() {
    Class clazz = Object.class; // or whatever class you want or need

    // this is what your method *will* return:
    List actualResult = parse("/path/to/somewhere", clazz);

    // best way would be to check each element:
    for(Object element : actualResult) {
        if (clazz.equals(element.getClass())) {
            // do your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

What I forgot:
I don't think that it es even possible to do this like you would like to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe convert the list?

```
List<TagsRun> myList = new Gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
List<Clazz> = Arrays.asList(myList.toArray(new Clazz[0]));
```

Edit:
I think this could help you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Class) - Scroll down to the List section, if you didn't notice it

Comment: The problem is that I have no **TagsRun** type in my method. I have only **Class** and can not set the type of List in runtime.

Comment: what type is new Gson.fromJson(json, collectionType); returning in your code? Object type would be a solution maybe, converting it later at a different stage ?!

Comment: either im getting something wrong, but couldn't you just do List<clazz.getClass()> ...

Comment: No, I can not. Because generic lists exist only at compilation time, not runtime. So it is not possible to parameterize a list in runtime.